# Virtual inheritance and same name members

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

I have the the following classes:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() { x = 3; }
    int x;
    virtual void foo() {};
};

class Med1 : public virtual Base
{
public:
    int x;
    Med1() { x = 4; }
    virtual void foo() {};
};

class Med2 : public virtual Base
{
public:
    virtual void goo() {};
    virtual void foo() {};
};

class Der : public Med1, public Med2
{
public:
    Der() {}
    virtual void foo() {};
    virtual void goo() {};
};
```

And the following code:

```
Base* d = new Der;
d->foo();
cout << d->x;
```

Output:

```
 3
```

Why is that? `Med1` constructor is called after `Base` constructor. I'm guessing it's setting `Med1::x`, and not `Base::x`, but why is `Der::x` the same as `Base::x` and not `Med1::x`. Why is there no ambiguity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d` is a pointer to `Base`, so `d->x` refers unambiguously to `Base::x`. There would only be an ambiguity if it were a pointer to `Der`.

Comment: Ha! Makes sense, don't know why I missed that. But I changed the code and still no ambiguity. It prints `4` if I have a pointer to `Der`. Guess `Med1` hides `Base::x`.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is pointer to Base x will be of Base.
And the order of constructor is super class and then derived class. So constructor of Base class is called first and then of Der.

Comment: The first part of the answer is identical to Mike's. The second part I already stated in the question...

Answer (score -1):

The variable `x` is not virtual, so the compiler has to scratch its head and say - hang on you Base. Therefore it goes to `Base->x`

Comment: Of course in C++ a data member cannot be virtual. (I guess the downvote was about the fact that this answer implied that a variable could be virtual...) The point is that `Med1::x` does not override `Base::x`, because only a virtual **function** declaration can override other virtual function declarations.